# Transform the dataframe containing time series

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
datestamp              Name            Reading
2018-01-01 00:00:00    A01              40
2018-01-01 01:00:00    A01              50
2018-01-01 03:00:00    A01              50
2018-01-01 01:00:00    A02              50
2018-01-01 02:00:00    A02              40
2018-01-01 03:00:00    A02              30
```

Given a start and end date (start = `2018-01-01 00:00:00` and end = `2018-01-01 05:00:00`)

I would like to transform the dataframe to below. (for all missing entry we need to have zero or NULL)

Output like:

```
datestamp              Name            Reading
2018-01-01 00:00:00    A01              40
2018-01-01 01:00:00    A01              50
2018-01-01 02:00:00    A01              00
2018-01-01 03:00:00    A01              50
2018-01-01 04:00:00    A01              00
2018-01-01 05:00:00    A01              00
2018-01-01 00:00:00    A02              00
2018-01-01 01:00:00    A02              50
2018-01-01 02:00:00    A02              40
2018-01-01 03:00:00    A02              30
2018-01-01 04:00:00    A02              00
2018-01-01 05:00:00    A02              00
```

I directionless so have no approach as of now.

Comment: kindly accept one of the answers provided -- whatever was best solution for you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try pivot the table and reindex:

```
new_dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 
                          '2018-01-01 05:00:00', 
                          freq='H', name='datestamp')

(df.pivot_table(index='datestamp',columns='Name',
               values='Reading', fill_value=0)
   .reindex(new_dates, fill_value=0)
   .stack().sort_index(level=[1,0])
   .reset_index(name='Reading')
)
```

Output:

```
             datestamp Name  Reading
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00  A01       40
1  2018-01-01 01:00:00  A01       50
2  2018-01-01 02:00:00  A01        0
3  2018-01-01 03:00:00  A01       50
4  2018-01-01 04:00:00  A01        0
5  2018-01-01 05:00:00  A01        0
6  2018-01-01 00:00:00  A02        0
7  2018-01-01 01:00:00  A02       50
8  2018-01-01 02:00:00  A02       40
9  2018-01-01 03:00:00  A02       30
10 2018-01-01 04:00:00  A02        0
11 2018-01-01 05:00:00  A02        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.date_range(), df.loc[] and a nested for loop:

```
df

datestamp   Name    Reading
0   2018-01-01 00:00:00 A01 40
1   2018-01-01 01:00:00 A01 50
2   2018-01-01 02:00:00 A01 50
3   2018-01-01 03:00:00 A02 50
4   2018-01-01 04:00:00 A02 40
5   2018-01-01 05:00:00 A02 30
```

```
start_date = dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_date = dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01 05:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='H')
for date in date_range:
    for sensor in df.Name.unique():
        if len(df.loc[(df['datestamp'] == date) & (df['Name'] == sensor)]) == 0:
            df=df.append({'datestamp':date, 'Name':sensor, 'Reading':0}, ignore_index=True)
            
df = df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'datestamp']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
df


datestamp   Name    Reading
0   2018-01-01 00:00:00 A01 40
1   2018-01-01 01:00:00 A01 50
2   2018-01-01 02:00:00 A01 50
3   2018-01-01 03:00:00 A01 0
4   2018-01-01 04:00:00 A01 0
5   2018-01-01 05:00:00 A01 0
6   2018-01-01 03:00:00 A02 50
7   2018-01-01 04:00:00 A02 40
8   2018-01-01 05:00:00 A02 30
9   2018-01-01 00:00:00 A02 0
10  2018-01-01 01:00:00 A02 0
11  2018-01-01 02:00:00 A02 0
```

Pardon the column headings.

Answer (score -2):

You can use pandas fillna method, [Link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df[‘column_name’] = df[‘column_name’].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Which `na` values are being filled? I don't see na values in the input?

Comment: Sorry fillna doesn’t mean na value have to be there it replaces the cells with missing values with 0 or np.nan where np is numpy.

Comment: @PrasunBhattacharyya kindly re-read the question. I think you have misunderstood what the problem is.